# Intersystems Cache SQL shell: How to spool the output of a query to a file?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I am trying to create a script in UNIX to query the Cache database. I could get the output but how do I write the output to a file>
I used the following procedure:

```
cache << EOF
DO \$SYSTEM.SQL.Shell()
SELECTMODE DISPLAY
SELECT * from .....
GO
EXIT
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this for reports/webpages/etc I would look at the built in modules that Intersystems provides for Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.  These should give you a cleaner interface into the database.

That said, I do some external calls for monitoring purposes that don't use the language API because of what I am trying to get from the database (usually internals).  In those cases I use Perl.  I use Perl to because doing it this way I need to parse out the menus and other things I don't want (which you won't get with the APIs).  The following is a simple example looking at all the users that exist in Cache.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $username = 'user';
my $password = 'password'; 

my $val = `csession $instance -U %SYS << done
$username
$password

d ^SECURITY
1
3
*
*



h
done`;

my @users = split(/\n/, $val);
my $in_users = 0;
my $output = '';
foreach (@users){
     if($in_users){
    chomp($_);
    if($_ eq ''){
        #no longer listing users
        $in_users = 0;
    } else {
            $output .= "$_\n";
        } 
  }
  $in_users = 1 if($_ =~ m/^\-\-\-\-/);  # I started a the user list 
}

print $output; # this prints out to the console

#This prints to a file.
open(OUTFILE, ">outfile.txt");
print OUTFILE $output;
```

Check out the following links about the Perl and Python API
http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GBPL
and 
http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GBPY

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hackish, but the following should work:

```
echo -e "username\npassword\nDO \$SYSTEM.SQL.Shell()\nfoo\nbar\nH\n" | cache > output
```

Each command you would enter in Caché is followed by a "\n" to indicate a line return. That is then piped into a new session and its output is written to the file.